# javascript to display different google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need some javascript that will choose which GA tracking to use depending on URL.

If URL contains `it-it` use GA tracking code `UA-423234`, if URL contains `en-it` use tracking code `UA-734342`.

**Including Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "ssl."; : "");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    var gaGroupAccount = _gat._getTracker("UA-423234-1");
    gaGroupAccount._setDomainName("example.com");
} catch (err) { }
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    var pageTracker = 'gaGroupAccount';
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the google analytics code that you are including ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var gaGroupAccount = _gat._getTracker("UA-423234-1");
                gaGroupAccount._setDomainName("example.com");
            } catch (err) { }</script>
<script language="javascript">
var pageTracker = 'gaGroupAccount';
</script>

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some effort that you have put in and what research you have done.

Answer (score 1):

```
var code;
if(window.location.href.includes('it')){
    code = 'UA-423234' 
}else if(window.location.href.includes('en')){
    code = 'UA-734342'
}

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "ssl."; : "");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E")); 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
try { 
var gaGroupAccount = _gat._getTracker(code); 
gaGroupAccount._setDomainName("example.com"); 
} 
catch (err) { }
</script> 
<script language="javascript"> var pageTracker = 'gaGroupAccount'; </script>
```

Edit (after @Endless' comment)- The first part of the code can be written as

```
var code;
if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('it') !== -1){
    code = 'UA-423234' 
}else if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('en') !== -1){
    code = 'UA-734342'
}
```

Comment: be aware includes only works on chrome 41 and FF 40 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes